# CSS3 Columns aren't filling evenly

Tags: css, layout, multiple-columns

For a visual reference as to what I'm talking about, please see the following site and click into one of the subheader dropdown items:  http://bmgz.rtcgraphics.com/#3

This is a bit of a conceptual question but I have a set of three columns that I am filling using the following CSS3 declarations:

```
#bullets {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 20px 10%;
    z-index: 5;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-width: 23.333%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-width: 23.333%; /* Firefox */
    column-width: 23.333%;
    -webkit-column-fill: balance; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-fill: balance; /* Firefox */
    column-fill: balance;
    -webkit-column-span: all;
    -moz-column-span: all;
    column-span: all;
}
```

The columns are filling unevenly.  Sometimes the columns will fill such that the bullets fall in a set of 2, 2, and then 0 items in the last column.  Other times it will be 4, 4, 1.

I am very confused as to how the browser is deciding to fill the columns.  It seems to be consistent across all browsers.  My goal would be to have the columns fill horizontally left-to-right, so that a set of 4 items would fill 2, 1, 1

Any and all guidance would be so helpful!

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid but I don't see anything I would describe as a "subheader" on that page. Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: If you hover over one of the columns, there columns expand to show subheaders which you can click on and it will load a new page section.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a direct answer for this question, but if I just make the list items `float:left` and have `width: 33%` of the ul space, I get the effect I was looking for.  Lord only know why the built-in CSS columns fill so unevenly.

Comment: This seems to be a Chrome only issue.  I came here looking for an answer, as in Chrome, when I have 8 items in a list, they break into 2 columns as desired, BUT the left column takes 5 items, the right take sonly 3.   When I open same page on Firefox, it splits 4 and 4 as desired.

Comment: Just "solved" it!   I had `position: relative;` on my `li` list items so that I could implement a custom bullet solution.  Removing the position relative, the columns split into even counts of items, 4 and 4 in my one example.  NOTE: to still implement the custom bullets, I simply wrapped the inner text content with a span and applied the bullet to that.